# Unpack a tuple and assign a variable to the second value only if the first value is truthy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, walrus-operator

I have a Python function which returns a tuple with a boolean and string

```
def check_something():
    # ...
    return bool_value, str_messsage
```

Is there a way I can use the output of this function in an `if` statement using the boolean and assign the string value to a variable in the `if` statement

```
if not check_something():
    # ...
```

Answer (score 17):

```
if (result := check_something())[0]:
    var = result[1]
```

This uses the 'walrus operator', which is new syntax that was introduced in Python 3.8. You can read about it [here](https://realpython.com/python38-new-features/#the-walrus-in-the-room-assignment-expressions).

For Python <= 3.7, you have to include one extra line:

```
bool_val, str_message = check_something()
if bool_val:
    var = str_message
```